# Split Large Single Json array into multiple JSON arrays of 10K records

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, split

I have a CSV file having around 5 million records and i'm trying to convert the csv file data into json array using Json processor jq. However, i need to convert the csv into json arrays (into separate files) each having 10K records instead of a single json array file having 5 million records as given in below sample.

How do i achieve this via shell script ? OR How do i convert the single json array into multiple json arrays each having 10k records in json file via a shellscipt ?

Input csv file:

```
identifier,type,locale
91617676848,MSISDN,es_ES
91652560975,MSISDN,es_ES
91636563675,MSISDN,es_ES
```

csv to json conversion:

```
jq --slurp --raw-input --raw-output \
  'split("\n") | .[1:] | map(split(",")) |
      map({"identifier": .[0],
             "type": .[1],
             "locale": .[2]})' \
  sample.csv > out_new.json
```

Single Json array output:

```
[
  {
    "identifier": "91617676848",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "91652560975",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "91636563675",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  }
]
```

Expected Json output.

```
1.json  (having 10K json array records)
  [
  {
    "identifier": "91617676848",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  {
    "identifier": "91652560975",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  }
  ]


  2.json (having 10K json array records)
  [
  {
    "identifier": "91636563675",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .

  {
    "identifier": "91636563999",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth installing "csvkit" to use the "csvjson" program for this purpose.  (Use Homebrew on OS X.)
https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvjson.html

```
$ csvjson -I sample.csv | jq
[
  {
    "identifier": "91617676848",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "91652560975",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "91636563675",
    "type": "MSISDN",
    "locale": "es_ES"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Eric Bollinger, That's not possible as we are not allowed to install any such tool. Need a shell or bash while will have the logic to split the json array into small batches of 10K records

Comment: Anyone with any shell script ideas or command line in bash or awk ? Please it is a little urgent.

Comment: I suspect you encounter a 10K limit because "jq" builds the entire result set in memory before printing anything.  You're on the right track to consider a stream processing command like "sed" or "awk".  Here's an awk script to get you started:
`BEGIN { print "[" }; { print "your work here" }; END { print "]" }`
But I'm not doing your homework for free.